# Hamburger Menu Icon class toggling

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hamburger-menu

I have implemented a hamburger icon using font awesome icons fa-bars and fa-close icons.

```
<div class="btn-group box" id="homeNavMenuBox" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">
    <button type="button" class="homenavmenu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div aria-expanded="true" class="navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse in">
    <ul>
        <li> About </li>
        <li> Info</li>
        <li> Logout</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Now, On click of the div, toggling the class to close icon. Clicking on Close icon will bring bars icon back thus giving the feeling of menu and close icons.

```
function toggleMenu(menuClass) {
    jQuery(menuClass).find('span').toggleClass('fa fa-bars fa fa-close');
}
```

It works fine with normal clicks, however, when user rapidly clicks on icons, their roles are getting reversed, i.e. when menu gets expanded instead of close icon, I am getting menu icon and vice versa

[Expected and Actual functionalities of Menu Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p9a1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the icon CSS classes on toggle, attach the menu to the "shown" and "hidden" custom collapse events exposed by the [Bootstrap API](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events). This will help ensure the menu is completely opened or completely closed prior changing the icons, which should help with avoiding the wrong icons appearing at the wrong time:

HTML:

```
<div id="someIdentifier" aria-expanded="true" class="navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse in">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $menu = $('#homeNavMenuBox');
    var $toggle = $menu.find('span');

    // query collapsing element to attach event handlers to
    var $collapse = $('#someIdentifier');

    $collapse.on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
        toggleMenu();
    });

    $collapse.on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
        toggleMenu();
    });

    function toggleMenu() {
        $toggle.toggleClass("fa-bars fa-close");
    }
});
```

Also this demonstrating storing the jQuery query rather for the `span` rather than executing a new jQuery query each toggle as both `#homeNavMenuBox` and the `span` will likely be present the entire time.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Nice answer. $toggle and $span should be named the same though.

Comment: Thank you Alexander Staroselsky, I will try the above approach, just wondering homeNavMenuBox is the div which holds the icon button and the menu that gets expanded is in second div which starts at <div aria-expanded="true"..>. I have to give ID to that second div and consider it as $menu, Am i correct?

Comment: Good question. For the custom Bootstrap Collapse API events, you would want to target the actual collapsible element, in your case the `div` with class `collapse`. I'd add an `id` to the that collapse element. I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Great Alexander Staroselsky. It worked. I did a slight modification by changing 'shown.bs.collapse' to 'show.bs.collapse' as the first one gives a delay in changing icons (may be waiting for CSS transitions to complete).

Comment: Great to hear! Keep these custom events in mind when working with Bootstrap, gives you access to some unique events across all of their JavaScript components. I've found them to be indispensable.

Answer (score 1):

An other option would be to use the second argument for the toggleClass method, that determines the state.

```
function toggleMenu(menuClass) {
var el = jQuery(menuClass).find('span');
el.toggleClass('fa-bars fa-close', function(){
    return el.hasClass('fa-bars');
});
```

}

The class will now be toggled depending on whether the menu is open or not.

Comment: Thank you NotABlueWhale. I have tried this and somehow the class toggling is not happening properly, it stays as 'fa fa-bars fa-2x fa-close'. Now, to make icon proper size, i have added fa-2x

Comment: My bad, I've updated my answer and it should work this time.